# Operator Error of DocumentSnapshot on User Model

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my first question and I am not professional about coding, am just aiming to develop myself so I hope I can explain myself.

I have been trying to develop a social platform and I am having trouble on user model which is connected with firebase. You can see my user model below:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

    class User {
      final String id;
      final String profileName;
      final String username;
      final String url;
      final String email;
      final String bio;
    
      User({
        this.id,
        this.profileName,
        this.username,
        this.url,
        this.email,
        this.bio,
    });
    
      factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
        return User(
          id: doc.id,
          profileName: doc['profileName'],
          username: doc['username'],
          url: doc['photoUrl'],
          email: doc['email'],
          bio: doc['bio'],
        );
      }
    }
```

When I create user model like this, I get "The Operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'DocumentSnapshot'." error as you can see on the screenshot.

[image: ScreenShot]

I have spent 3 days to find the solution but I couldn't find similar problems on the internet. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Or try adding `()` after data

```
factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
        return User(
          id: doc.id,
          profileName: doc.data()['profileName'],
          username: doc.data()['username'],
          url: doc.data()['photoUrl'],
          email: doc.data()['email'],
          bio: doc.data()['bio'],
        );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using doc.data[' ']

```
factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
        return User(
          id: doc.id,
          profileName: doc.data['profileName'],
          username: doc.data['username'],
          url: doc.data['photoUrl'],
          email: doc.data['email'],
          bio: doc.data['bio'],
        );
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! By the way, when I write like "doc.data['profileName]," the error didn't disappear. I wrote like "doc.data()['profileName]," and then it worked. On the other hand, I couldn't find this without your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this solution will help someone facing the same issue

try using dynamic as below if you are using null-safety

```
factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
 final data = doc.data() as dynamic;
    return User(
     id: doc.id,
     profileName: doc['profileName'],
     username: doc['username'],
     url: doc['photoUrl'],
     email: doc['email'],
     bio: doc['bio'],
    );
   }
```

or store only the doc.data in final

```
factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
 final data = doc.data();
    return User(
     id: doc.id,
     profileName: doc['profileName'],
     username: doc['username'],
     url: doc['photoUrl'],
     email: doc['email'],
     bio: doc['bio'],
    );
   }
```